# How do I fold a list of related vertices with the primary vertex?

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am trying to retrieve some Identity vertices and any Groups they are a part of. The graph structure looks something like this. Note that the Organization has multiple users, all of which I'm trying to select, and each of those users can be in multiple groups. (This is, essentially, the standard user-account-with-groups arrangement.)

```
alice  = g.addV('Identity').property('email', 'alice@example.test').next()
alfred = g.addV('Identity').property('email', 'alfred@example.test').next()

org = g.addV('Organization').property('name', 'Example Inc').next()
[alice, alfred].each { g.V(org).addE('user').to(it).iterate() }

a = g.addV('Group').property('name', 'starts with A').next()
f = g.addV('Group').property('name', 'five letters').next()
[a, f].each { g.V(it).addE('member').to(alice).iterate() }
g.V(A).addE('member').to(alfred).iterate()
```

The main logic of my traversal works as expected:

```
gts.V(organization)
  .out(ORG_USERS).as('i')
  .in(GROUP_USERS)
    .valueMap('name').with(tokens)
    .as('g')
  .select('i', 'g')
    .by(__.valueMap('email').with(tokens))
  .toList()
```

This produces, however, a list of maps with keys `i` and `g`, in particular duplicating an Identity if it's in multiple Groups. Instead, I'd like to fold the Groups. I tried like so (not trying to deduplicate the actual Group results yet, just grouping them by Identity):

```
gts.V(organization)
  .out(ORG_USERS).as('i')
  .in(GROUP_USERS)
    .valueMap('name').with(tokens)
    .fold()
    .as('gs')
  .select('i', 'gs')
    .by(__.valueMap('email').with(tokens))
  .toList()
```

However, even though the `fold()` receives a traverser with an incoming Group-as-map, and simply returning the result of `fold()` produces the expected nested list, the `select('i', 'gs')` returns zero results. (I can `select('gs')`, but both `select('i')` and `select('i', 'gs')` are empty.)

How should I structure a traversal so I can get the desired tuple of (Identity, List[Group])?

Comment: After a `fold` step the previous labels like `i` are lost. You should be able to just rewrite a little and use `project`. If you can add some basic `addE` and `addV` steps that build a sample graph that would make testing an answer easier.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Added. In the real code, there's also a "where group is defined by organization" backreference; I'll edit to include that if it'll make a substantial difference, but that seemed like just hanging a `.where(...)` right after the `in(GROUP_USERS)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample data I changed the query, by way of example, to use a `project` step. If this is not quite what you are looking for we can iterate a bit.

```
gremlin>   g.V(org).
......1>     project('i','g').
......2>       by(out().valueMap().fold()).
......3>       by(out().in().valueMap().fold()) 

==>[i:[[email:[alice@example.test]]],g:[[name:[starts with A]],[name:[five letters]],[name:[Example Inc]]]]
```

If you need the `project` step to apply to the fan out from the org that can be achieved using

```
gremlin>  g.V(org).
......1>     out().
......2>     project('i','g').
......3>       by(valueMap().fold()).
......4>       by(__.in().valueMap().fold())      

==>[i:[[email:[alice@example.test]]],g:[[name:[starts with A]],[name:[five letters]],[name:[Example Inc]]]]
```

UPDATED based on discussion below. Using the `group` step yields a grouping from e-mails to the connections they have.

```
gremlin> g.V(org).
......1>    out().
......2>    group().
......3>      by(values('email')).
......4>      by(__.in().values('name').fold()).
......5>    unfold()

==>alfred@example.test=[starts with A, Example Inc]
==>alice@example.test=[starts with A, five letters, Example Inc]
```

Comment: This seems like it collects all of the `i` and all of the `g` but without any correlation between the two (i.e., which users are associated with which groups).

Comment: In the sample graph, Alice is connected to all of those groups. Could you please show the output you would like to see? `gremlin> g.V(org).out().in().path().by(valueMap())
==>[[name:[Example Inc]],[email:[alice@example.test]],[name:[starts with A]]]
==>[[name:[Example Inc]],[email:[alice@example.test]],[name:[five letters]]]
==>[[name:[Example Inc]],[email:[alice@example.test]],[name:[Example Inc]]] `

Comment: I'll extend my example; the case is that there can be many `i` per origin vertex, and I need to know both the list of Identities and the Groups they're in.

Comment: Additionally, will `project` work if I'm also needing to say `/*group*/.where(__in('definedBy').is('org')`, something like `project('gs').by(__.in('member').where(__.in('definedBy').is('org')))` (i.e., "the groups where this user is a member and the group is defined by the original organization")?

Comment: I will try and update the answer (as soon as I can). Replacing `project` with `group` might be all you need to do here though. Group by all the `i` and by their incoming vertices.

Comment: I added another example that uses `group` is that closer to what  you need?